# SQL multi-table JOIN

Tags: sql, join, left-join

I need your help with SQL query with 3 tables.

**1st table (#chats)**
chatId; firstUserId; secondUserId

**2nd table (#users)**
userId; userNickname

**3rd table (#messages)**
messageId, chatId; messageToWalletId; readIndicator

[image]

I need to receive:

1. List of all #chats WHERE firstUserId = ? or secondUserId = ?
2. For particular output from 1) add userNickname from table users where relation chats.firstUserId=users.userId + chats.secondUserId=users.userId
3. **Get only 1 last message from #messages table and return "messageToWalletId" and "readIndicator" WHERE chatId = chatId from point 1) (ps.: there are more messages to the same chatId so only 1 last message (order by messageId)**

First two points are simple:

```
        $queryGetChats = '
            SELECT 
                t1.chatId, t1.firstUserId, t1.secondUserId, 
                t2.userNickname AS firstUserNickname, 
                t3.userNickname AS secondUserNickname
            FROM chat AS t1
                LEFT JOIN users AS t2 ON t1.firstUserId = t2.userId
                LEFT JOIN users AS t3 ON t1.secondUserId = t3.userId
            WHERE firstUserId = ? OR secondUserId = ? 
            ORDER BY t1.chatId DESC;
        ';
        $paramsChats = (array($userId, $userId));
        
        return Db::queryAll($queryGetChats, $paramsChats);
```

But I can not figure out the third one if I need to create WHERE clause with chatId from table #chats, it can not be passed to LEFT JOIN (SELECT ...).

> So the output would have an array with:
> array(chatId, firstUserId, secondUserId, firstUserNickname, secondUserNickname, messageToWalletId, readIndicator)

Thank you for your help

Comment: I have forgot to mention that the output might consists of more chats and thus return multiarray. I got "Operand should contain 1 column(s)". So for the call can happen: 1) User has 5 chats (based on SELECT condition) 2) Each chat return to array including the fields mentioned 3) Final will be returned array of arrays of chats

Answer (score 0):

```
with messages_sort as (
Select
 m.*,
 rank() over (partition by chatId order by messageId desc) as rn
from messages m 
)

Select 
 messageToWalletId, readIndicator
from messages_sort 
where rn = 1
and chatId in (Select chatId from chats) -- you can change this select statement with the query for point 1 that returns the chatId's for that scenario.
```

;

Comment: Thank you. I have forgot to mention that the output might consists of more chats and thus return multiarray. The last section "Operand should contain 1 column(s)".

So for the call can happen:
1) User has 5 chats (based on SELECT condition)
2) Each chat return to array including the fields mentioned
3) Final will be returned array of arrays of chats

Comment: Any update, please?